# Crear <td> dependiendo "X" numero que yo pase

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero crear en un tabla X numero de `<td>` dependiendo un numero X que yo le pase, para lo cual tengo la siguiente funcion.

```
function holaMateriales(){
  var cont =13;
  peticionDatos(
    '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/supervisor/supinicio/datos',
      {},
    function(){},
    function(datos){

         var matT = "<tr></td>"; 

         $(datos).each(function(i,e){

            matT += "<td id='c-"+e.mcID+"'>"+ e.mcNombre+"</td>"+
            "<td id='c-"+e.presID+"'>"+ e.pres+"</td>"+td+"</tr>";
           console.log(cont);
          });
          $("#materiales").append(matT);

        });
}
```

lo que hace es crear X numero de `<tr>` dependiendo lo que le pase, ahora lo que quiero es crear 15 `<td>` para cada `<tr>`

> | Mat |  Des  |  td1 |  td2 | etc |  etc.....

hasta que se crren los 15  que quiero, los cuales empezaran despues del  Des

Alguien que me pueda ayudar....¿?

Comment: Es algo confuso lo que preguntas, con buen ánimo te lo digo. Tu código es algo extraño. Debes darte a entender mejor, quieres crear un número determinado de **tr** y dentro de él, un número determinado de **td**, estoy mal?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cuestiones aquí:

A mi parecer esta linea `var matT = "<tr></td>";` no debería llevar el `</td>` y debería estar dentro del ciclo `each`. El `<tr>` debe estar en un ciclo para que se creen las filas, dentro de ese ciclo y hay que poner los 15 td de apertura y cierre con su contenido.

Ojo no se pueden hacer tablas identadas(bueno no deberían hacerse), porque tendrás muchos problemas. Si defines 15 columnas todas las filas tendrán 15 columnas, o si son 10 todas tendrán diez. **Si sabes la cantidad de columnas pon las 15, pero si puede variar en cada construcción de la tabla, necesitaras otro ciclo.**

Pero para que recibas una buena ayuda necesitamos ver que trae la variable `datos`.

Yo armo una tabla vacia en javascript que despues lleno con un jquery datatables de la siguiente manera:

```
var txtTemp;
var thTemp;
var tblHead = document.createElement("thead");
var filaHead = document.createElement("tr");
var encabezados=new Array("COLUMNA1","COLUMNA2","COLUMNA3","COLUMNAN",);
tabla = document.createElement("table");
tabla.setAttribute("cellpadding", "0");
tabla.setAttribute("cellspacing", "0");
tabla.setAttribute("border", "0");
tabla.setAttribute("id", "tblRevalidacion");
tabla.setAttribute("class", "display");
tabla.setAttribute("width", "100%");
filaHead.setAttribute("class", "display");
for(var i=0;i<encabezados.length;i++){
        txtTemp=document.createTextNode(encabezados[i]);
        thTemp=document.createElement("th");
        thTemp.appendChild(txtTemp);
        filaHead.appendChild(thTemp);
}   
tblHead.appendChild(filaHead);
tabla.appendChild(tblHead);

var divAplicacion = document.getElementById("aplicacion");
divAplicacion.appendChild(tabla);
```

Para ello agregue un `div id=aplicación` al html y la tabla se genera dentro de el. Mi tabla solo tiene los encabezados porque te comente después la lleno con un jquery datatables. Tambien sería bueno que hicieras un `console.log(matT)` para que veas como esta tu tabla y no andes a ciegas.